# jQuery draggable problem with 'scroll' on object inside overflow:hidden container when using appendTo: 'body'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I have a draggable object, with that can be accepted in several droppables..  I have put all the droppables in a container, and simply want to be able to detect when the draggable is hovering over the container of droppables...

At first, I tried making use of the 'over' and 'out' callbacks for droppables, but it was not working because hovering from one droppable to another (inside the same container) was causing it to think the mouse had left the container...

So my next approach was to in the drag start callback, do an event listener for mouseenter and mouseleave on the container-- and then stop listening on the drag stop callback...

However, this results in total crazy behavior...  If you look at my example page:

http://collinatorstudios.com/www/jquery_draggable_test.html

When dragging the box to the red dropzone, you should see "enter" when the mouseenter event fires, and "leave" when mouseleave happens..  However, just dragging the box over the inside of the container causes "leave" to appear a zillion times.....  I cannot figure out why this is happening, nor what solution there is to my problem so I can do what I need to.  I've been working on this for almost 4 hours now and am losing my mind over what seems like it should be so simple to achieve.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to bind to the events once! There is no need to bind and unbind them each time... I separated them out in the code below to make it more clear about binding once.

And as ZDYN said (+1 to him), you need to include a droppable code, but instead of using the container, use the zones inside... here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/TKP5J/) and the full code below.

```
var feedback = $('#feedback');

$('.item').draggable({
    revert: true,
    zIndex: 999,
    cursor: 'move'
});

$('.drop_zone').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.appendTo($(this));
    }
}).bind('dropover dropout', function(e) {
    var id = this.id;
    feedback.text(e.type === 'dropover' ? 'Over: ' + id : 'Out: ' + id);
});
```

Comment: Hi fudgey, would you mind explaining exactly what you did there?  You appended the draggable to the dropzone?  That means that the element is being moved so that it is a child of the dropzone?  What is the reason to do this?

Comment: Hi Patrick!, the usual reason for drag and drop is to move an item from place to another. If you look at this droppable demo (http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager) you see that the item is dropped in a trash can. If you are making a shopping cart then you'll want to clone the object before appending it.

Comment: Oh ok.. at first glance I wasn't sure what you were doing because of the additional .bind added to the actual drop callback. However, after looking it over, your code still doesn't accomplish what I am looking for. What I really am wanting to do is start/stop tracking mouse movement when the draggable goes within the outer container, so I had simplified it to just be able to detect when it was over/out of the container.  I made a new fiddle-- but the over/out for the container gets called when dragging from one drop zone to another, and I don't know why. http://jsfiddle.net/4hDa8/

Comment: Also, notice that I added "greedy: true" to the child dropzones-- and still you can drop inside the container and the container's drop function gets triggered........

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a droppable for the container:

```
$('#drop_zone_container').droppable({
    over: function(){ feedback.text('enter')},
    out: function(){feedback.text('leave')}
});
```

Comment: I tried that and it was unsuccessful.  It was causing weird behavior where sometimes the droppable container was registering the drop event instead of the droppables inside the container...  So, the drop events for the inner droppables were not getting called because apparently the drop for the outer container was getting triggered...  But it was weird and intermittent, seemed very buggy when I tried to use it.

Comment: @patrick, try giving the child elements the option `greedy: true` in their droppables. See this page for more details: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#propagation.